# LOGGER IN r, msg function in R

Tags: r, logging

I am a beginner in R,
While I have to edit some pre written codes in R.
there is a specific one which I cannot understand.
it would be really helpful if anyone can help me understand this.

```
# Logger
log.msg = function(msg){
  ## capture messages and errors to a file.
  fileConn<-file("output.txt", open = "a+")
  writeLines(c(msg), fileConn)
  close(fileConn)
}

 log.msg("Start Data extraction and merging..")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
log.msg = function(msg){
  ## capture messages and errors to a file.

  ## create file connection in append mode (a+)
  fileConn<-file("output.txt", open = "a+")

  ## write the msg to this file
  writeLines(c(msg), fileConn)

  ## close connection
  close(fileConn)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is helpful